# Editar un archivo csv en java

Tags: java, csv

Necesito editar archivos csv pero los paquetes disponibles que he visto para manipular estos archivos (com.opencsv y javacsv) no editan en función del estado actual del archivo, sino que siempre lo reescriben. Este código muestra de manera simplificada lo que quiero hacer:

```
      import com.opencsv.*;
      import java.io.File;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.io.FileReader;
      import java.io.FileWriter;
      import java.io.IOException;

      public class mainLD {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      CSVWriter csvWriter;
        try {
        csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("E:/archivo.csv"); 
        String[] tes=new String[3];

            tes[0]="Primero";
            tes[1]="Segundo";
            tes[2]="tercero";

            csvWriter.writeNext(tes);
            csvWriter.close();
             }
            catch(Exception ee) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }}}
```

Con este código lo que esperaba era que cada vez que se ejecute "csvWriter.writeNext(tes)" en corridas independientes del programa, se escriba en la línea siguiente del archivo csv. Es decir, que se escriba una nueva línea cada vez que se corre el programa, pero en vez de esto se reescribe siempre la primera línea. Por otro lado en ninguno de los dos paquetes hay algún método que pida como parámetro el número de línea que se quiere escribir o alguna instrucción de salto de línea. Tendría que usar otra librería? O hay algún método que me ayude en alguna de estas dos librerías (com.opencsv y javacsv)? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder concatenar el contenido al fichero, solo debes incluir el parámetro booleano **true** en el FileWriter:

`csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("E:/archivo.csv", true);`

[Más información acerca de FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).

Answer (score 0):

estaba leyendo este tema, pero el código de ejemplo no funciona directamente, buscando ayuda encontré este código, tal vez pueda ayudar a alguien que intenta editar y poner una nueva línea en un archivo csv.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class FileWriterExample 
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {    
          try 
          {    
                FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D:\\usuarios.csv", true);    
                fw.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                fw.write(" Welcome to javaTpoint.");    
                fw.close();    
          }
          catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}    
          System.out.println("Success...");    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Estás en SO en español así que no hay necesidad de escribir en inglés